# runwithfriends licensing information

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I cant find the licensing information for runwithfriends sample FB app. Can any one please point me to a link with this info? Searched exhaustively but cant find anything. I want to edit this app a lot to make my own app since the functionality of my app is little similar.

Can we freely use sample apps to build our own? Are they bound with a license?

Comment: The users on [so] are not lawyers... We can't provide you with legal advice.  However - IMO, I don't think that there will be any problem if you use one of the sample apps as a starting point to create your own application...

Comment: It's licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0

https://github.com/fbsamples/runwithfriends/blob/master/main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing info can be found at the top of main.py.